# Get ocl string attribute length

Tags: string, ocl

I need to check an string attribute length and I don't know what function I have to use, `size()` maybe?

```
Context Myclass inv:self.string_attribute->size() <7
```

Answer (score 1):

`->` is for navigating from Collections.

`.` is for objects/values and an attribute is a value so:

```
...string_attribute.size()
```